How to update a BigQuery table with data from a local csv file while using Python?
Every day, I migrate data from a MySQL database to BigQuery. For most processes, I use LoadJobConfig().writedisposition with WRITE_APPEND. However, for my raw_stock table, using WRITE_APPEND doesn't work because I need to update the existing data instead.
I have a local file in .csv format with a header, containing only the rows that need updating. They are identified by id_store and id_product (which form a composite primary key). The columns to be updated are product_amount and date_update.
The entire process is done through Python. The necessary libraries and credentials are already set up.
My attempts resulted in either deleting and replacing the data or adding new rows. I specifically need the updates and nothing else. I tried searching for information in the documentation provided by GCP but was unsuccessful in finding the correct answer.
I'm still a novice in this area and unsure how to handle the updates. How can I proceed?
Update
I tried to implement a solution similar to the one suggested by jmorl96. It ended up being slightly different. Here's the code:
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
updated_rows = 0
                for index, row in df.iterrows():
                    id_product = row['id_product']
                    id_store = row['id_store']
                    date_update = row['date_update']
                    product_amount = row['product_amount']
                    query = f'''
                                UPDATE {projeto}.{dataset}.{table}
                                SET date_update = '{date_update}',
                                    product_amount = {product_amount}
                                WHERE id_product = {id_product} AND id_store = {id_store}
                                '''
                    try:
                        update_job = client.query(query)
                        update_job.result()
                        print(f"{table} updated.")
                        updated_rows += update_job.num_dml_affected_rows
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f'Error while updateing {nova_tabela}: {e}')

However, I noticed a potentially serious problem. Each updated line took about half a second to be effective. Considering that I have around two thousand updates daily, I am concerned about the overall time this process would take, but more importantly, I'm worried about the associated cost — given that we are dealing with the GCP environment.
I am almost considering that perhaps in this case, the best idea would be to generate a .CSV file with the entire original MySQL table at the end of the day and, using a LoadJobConfig adjusted to WRITE_TRUNCATE, overwrite the data of the relevant table. I think it will be more economical and faster than doing updates one by one. What do you think?

There is no native method to achieve that behavior. The simplest way to perform this is by creating a parameterized update query in Python and executing it while looping over the data of your input csv file.
For example, something like this:
for row in csv_file:   
    QUERY = (f"""
        UPDATE `your-project.your-dataset.your-table`
        SET product_amount = {row[2]},
        SET date_update = {row[3]}
        WHERE id_store = {row[0]} AND id_product = {row[1]}
    """)
    client.query_and_wait(QUERY)  # API request

Update: 25/07
Given that new information, the most effective solution would be:

Upload your CSV file to a new BigQuery table
Perform a Merge against the original table, updating when rows are matched, or perform a batching update as you can see in this example
Delete the new table you created, or leave it there and write_truncate it next day

You could code all these steps to automate the process. By doing this, you will avoid being charged multiple times, and loading times should not be a problem.

Hello, jmorl96. Thank you for your response. The information that there is no native method for such a task has already saved me a lot of research. I tried a solution similar to the one you suggested. I will edit the main text to discuss this and also mention the associated problem I had to make it easier for others who may also share the same doubt.

Hi! I have added a new approach based on the new information from your update.

Hello, jmorl96! I really liked the approach you proposed! Later on, I'll turn it into code - automating the creation and deletion of the temporary table as well. I'll get back to you with more information afterward. Thanks again!
